# Merging pushed named branch with default causes error

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, branch

I created a named branch using the mercurial eclipse plugin `20111225_Content_Build` and after committing this branch locally, i pushed to my bitbucket repository without first merging with `default`. Now i have the default (inactive) and my named branch `20111225_Content_Build` (active). I tried to merge these two following these steps:

```
hg update default
```

This gives me an error: `abort: untracked file in working directory differs from file in requested revision: 'target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/org.bixin.dugsi/Dugsi_Manager/pom.xml'`

and then when i try to merge: `hg merge 20111225_Content_Build` i get an error stating that i cannot merge with a working directory?

```
abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect
```

I do have several generated `target/` files that have not been committed or pushed, do i need to push these files in order to merge these two branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message when you update is telling you your `pom.xml` files is not added in your branch, but is added in default.  So when you `hg update default` Mercurial would need to discard the changes in your `pom.xml` file and overwrite it with the version that's checked-in in `default`, but Mercurial **always** refused to throw away data unless you really, really insist.

You've got two easy options:

*If you want to keep the changes you made to `pom.xml` in the branch* and merge them into the pom.xml stored in the `default` branch then you do this:

- `hg add target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/org.bixin.dugsi/Dugsi_Manager/pom.xml`
- `hg commit target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/org.bixin.dugsi/Dugsi_Manager/pom.xml`

*If (instead) you want to discard the changes to `pom.xml` in the branch* then just do this:

- `rm target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/org.bixin.dugsi/Dugsi_Manager/pom.xml`

After either one of those you'll be able to do:

- `hg update default`
- `hg merge 20111225_Content_Build`

Comment: after merging the branch with the default, i get a new head (tip) that has not been pushed. Can i update my bitbucket repository by pushing the new head revision?

Comment: Yup.  Merges are real changesets, and when you push it you'll have sent out a message saying "*this* is the right way to merge these two heads".  Anyone else who pulls your change from bitbucket, and who has those two heads, will then have one fewer head, because you will have *taught* them how to merge them down to one head.